# Optimize script to flatten json output from API

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

I have a script that extracts data from an API, where the final output of `requests.get(url=url, auth=(user, password)).json()` is "all_results". The output is ~25K rows, but it contains nested fields.

The API is for portfolio data, and the `children` field is a dictionary holding ticker level information (so can be really large).

The script below flattens "all_results" and specifies only the columns I need:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for record in all_results:
    df = pd.DataFrame(record.get('children', {})) 
    df['contactId'] = record.get('contactId')
    df['origin'] = record.get('origin')
    df['description'] = record.get('description')    
    final_df = final_df.append(df)
```

It works perfectly with smaller samples, however when trying to run it over the whole data set- it takes HOURS. Can anyone propose something more efficient than my current script? Need it to run way faster than currently.

Thank you in advance!

-- Full script--

```
user = ''
password= ""

# Starting values
start = 0
rows = 1500
base_url = 'https://....?start={0}&rows={1}'

print ("Connecting to API..")
url = base_url.format(start,rows)
req = requests.get(url=url, auth=(user, password))
print ("Extracting data..")
out = req.json()

total_records = out['other']['numFound']
print("Total records found: "+ str(total_records))

results = out['resultList']
all_results = results

print ("First " + str(rows) + " rows were extracted")

# Results will be an empty list if no more results are found
while results:
    start += rows # Rebuild url based on current start
    url = base_url.format(start, rows)
    req = requests.get(url=url, auth=(user, password))
    out = req.json()
    results = out['resultList']
    all_results += results
    print ("Next " + str(rows) + " rows were extracted")

# All results will now contains all the responses of each request.
print("Total records returned from API: "+ str(len(all_results))) #should equal number of records in response

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for record in all_results:
    df = pd.DataFrame(record.get('children', {})) 
    df['contactId'] = record.get('contactId')
    df['origin'] = record.get('origin')
    df['description'] = record.get('description')    
    final_df = final_df.append(df)

final_df = final_df.reset_index()
del final_df['index']
final_df['ticker'] = final_df['identifier'].str.split('@').str.get(0) #extract ticker (anything before @)
final_df.drop_duplicates(keep='first') #removes duplicates

print('DataFrame from API created succesfully\n')
print(final_df.head(n=50))
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the part that's slow?

Comment: I have a print statement telling me when the loop finished extracting all the records, and then next step is to flatten the output, as per the above. Basically `First 1500 rows were extracted.. Next 1500 rows were extracted.. Next 1500 rows were extracted.. Last x rows were returned..
Total records returned from API: 23148`

Comment: Can you show the timing code? What you've shown here really shouldn't take that long.

Comment: Sorry how do I show timing code? I added entire code, perhaps it is stuck somewhere else and I am misunderstanding. To get to "Total records returned from API" takes about 10 minutes and then it is stuck from there four hours (that's the last print statement I see)

Comment: If I dont flatten the output at the `children` level and simply use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(all_results), orient='columns')` instead, the whole query runs in ~15 minutes. But flattening as above takes HOURS to run